# Bayes Chain Rule

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have been reading a paper on Bayesian Networks and Analytical Hierarchy Process.  I want to try and apply it to some of my own data.

The author states that he uses Bayes Chain Rule to calculate the probability of a single event.  Can you just rearrange Bayes rule to calculate P(A)?  He hasn't shown any working out and just jumps to an answer that I can't seem to see where it comes from.

I eventually want to be able to complete a conditional probability table from weightings from the AHP.

Thank you

EDIT - This is part of my BN and I am trying to find the missing values [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbo43.jpg)

Comment: The chain rule is applied to a joint probability distribution of the form $P(X_1, X_2,..., X_d)$ and just states the identity  $P(X_1,X_2,..., X_d) = P(X_1)P(X_2 | X_1)P(X_3 | X_2, X_1) ... P(X_d | X_1, ..., X_{d-1})$. I don't know whether It's the *Bayes* chain rule, you are looking for. Observe that you can change the index order.

Comment: Thank you.  If I had three events, X1, X2 and X3, and wanted to find P(X1) could I do that?

Comment: What probabilities do you have ?

Comment: In a Bayesian network you have a more structured joint probability than the general case. In fact, the graph is a representation for the relationships between all random variables in the model. For example, in the the image you attached, the joint probability should be $P(A,B,C,D,E) = P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A)P(D|B)P(E|D,C)$ this is because the graph states that given $A$, $C$ is conditionally independent of $B$ so instead of $P(C|A,B)$ as stated by the chain rule, you can just write $P(C|B)$. The same occurs in node $D$ and finally in node $E$.